# Microphone list (input device list) in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, input, device, microphone

I am wondering how can I ask Windows and retrieve a list over current input devices?
Language is C++.
The goal is to select from the list in a program I am making.
Tried searching a bit, but found nothing..

Please help :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through the WaveIn Windows API. Since there is already a post with code to enumarate and retrieve the names of input devices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449162/get-the-full-name-of-a-wavein-device) I won't make a new one.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of future reference, it might be worth mentioning the [RtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/index.html) library, which is also written in C++ and is multiplatform on Windows, OS-X and Linux.

On Windows you can compile it either using the **ASIO SDK** (in case your devices have an ASIO driver), **DirectSound** (part of DirectX, old and deprecated, but still working), or **WASAPI** (introduced in Windows Vista).

With RtAudio you can manage devices very easily with class method calls such as:

```
RtAudio::startStream();
RtAudio::stopStream();
RtAudio::getDeviceCount();
RtAudio::getDefaultInputDevice();
RtAudio::getDeviceInfo(uint deviceID);
```

You can also manage output devices in the same fashion.