# How to get full name of microphone in C#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to get full name of all connected microphones. I was googling to find out an answer but there was no answer that satisfies me.

Let me show some examples:

1.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mo = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_SoundDevice");

foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in mo.Get())
{               
    MessageBox.Show(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString());  
    // or 
    MessageBox.Show(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString());  
    //or
    MessageBox.Show(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer").ToString()); 
    //or 
    MessageBox.Show(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString());
    //or
    MessageBox.Show(soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("ProductName").ToString());                     
}
```

All of these getters shows: "Device Audio USB" or "Device compatible with High Definition standard".

2.

```
WaveInCapabilities[] devices = GetAvailableDevices();        
foreach(device in devices)
{
    MessageBox.Show(device.ProductName);
}
```

The same answer: "Device Audio USB" or "Device compatible with High Definition standard".

I want to get the full name. I mean, something like: "Sennheiser microphone USB". Is it even possible? I found: [Get the full name of a waveIn device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449162/get-the-full-name-of-a-wavein-device) but a link in it is broken and I don't see any dsound.lib for c# (to use DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate).
Am I missing anything? Or is there any other option?

Comment: Is the full name of your device visible *anywhere* in Windows? (Device manager, etc.)

Comment: @Heinzi No, I don't see the full name of device in Device Manager. Does it mean it is impossible to do?

Comment: Well, if Windows does not know the full device name, I don't think that there's a ways to retrieve it. (But I'm no expert on Windows API, so I'd be happy if someone could prove me wrong.)

Comment: I think you are right. I switched USB connector and I have now the name using second example and @AnkurTripathi 's example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@AnkurTripathi answer is correct but it returns a name that contains up to 32 characters. If anyone doesn't want this restriction then the best idea is to use an enumarator:

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);            
foreach (var device in devices)
    MessageBox.Show(device.friendlyName);
```

It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try Naudio https://naudio.codeplex.com/

```
for (int n = 0; n < WaveIn.DeviceCount; n++)
{
    this.recordingDevices.Add(WaveIn.GetCapabilities(n).ProductName);
    comboBoxAudio.Items.Add(WaveIn.GetCapabilities(n).ProductName);
}
```

for get Full Name(FriendlyName):

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
foreach (MMDevice device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active))
   {
           this.recordingDevices.Add(device.FriendlyName);
   }
```

Comment: There is the same answer as mentioned above. In this example the ProductName has only 31 characters.

Comment: @Darooks Is the full name of your device visible anywhere in Windows? - If not - there is no more information available

Comment: @Cadburry I had to change the USB. There is the full name in Device Manager now.  I haven't noticed it before.

Comment: @AnkurTripathi It is right answer but it returns device name with 31 characters, is it possible to get the name without this restriction?

Comment: can you show me what is the device name and what return comes from your code ? its work for me and getting full name

Comment: @AnkurTripathi The name of my device is: "Sennheiser USB Headset". The code returns: "Microphone ( 2 -- Sennheiser USB" 32 characters. My goal is to get out of this restriction.